# Removing CSS declaration breaks other declarations in block, but only for buttons in Chrome

Tags: css, button, chromium

I've narrowed this down to the following HTML, which causes strange effects in Chrome:

```html
   <style type="text/css">
      #btn1, .text1 {
        font-family: courier;
        font-size:   42px;
        background:  pink;  /* BUG?? Removing this line breaks btn1's font */
      }
      #btn2, .text2 {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size:   42px;
        background:  cyan;
      }
    </style>
 
    <input type='button' id='btn1' onclick='alert("btn1")' value='Button1'> &nbsp;
    <input type='button' id='btn2' onclick='alert("btn2")' value='Button2'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text1' value='Text1'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text2' value='Text2'>
```

When the declaration line containing `background: pink;` is removed, it breaks the font-family and font-size for the button with the ID `btn1`, but the input with class `text1` is fine, and only in Chrome (I've only tested Chrome and Firefox).

It doesn't seem to matter if I change classes to IDs or vice versa; it's always the button that loses its font characteristics.  Furthermore, it doesn't seem to make a difference where `background: pink;` appears within the block; as long it's there, the font seems to be as expected.

Comment: Playing further with this, I find that 'font-weight: bold' also stops working.  And if I use the declaration 'cursor: crosshair;' or 'color: red' in place of 'background: pink;', it doesn't have the same "restorative" powers of fixing the font.

Comment: I don't understand what you are facing but in your code font-size is not declared properly for #btn1, #text1, It should be font-size: 42px;

Comment: Thanks vedankita -- I fixed that (and edited my OP), but it doesn't change the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine as per your styles given. `font-size: 42` which is not going to apply anything because it is not a valid syntax. It should be like `font-size:42px` as its in `#btn2`. After that if you remove/add the background, that's not changing any of the styles. Look at the following snippet(I didn't apply `font-size:42px`, and running as it is your code).

```css
#btn1, .text1 {
        font-family: courier;
        font-size:   42;
        background:  pink;  /* BUG?? Removing this line breaks btn1's font */
      }
      #btn2, .text2 {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size:   42px;
        background:  cyan;
      }
```

```html
<input type='button' id='btn1' onclick='alert("btn1")' value='Button1'> &nbsp;
    <input type='button' id='btn2' onclick='alert("btn2")' value='Button2'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text1' value='Text1'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text2' value='Text2'>
```

Now I will remove the `background: pink` from your code. Look at the snippet below.

```css
#btn1, .text1 {
        font-family: courier;
        font-size:   42;        
      }
      #btn2, .text2 {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size:   42px;
        background:  cyan;
      }
```

```html
<input type='button' id='btn1' onclick='alert("btn1")' value='Button1'> &nbsp;
    <input type='button' id='btn2' onclick='alert("btn2")' value='Button2'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text1' value='Text1'> <p>
    <input type='text' class='text2' value='Text2'>
```

Look at the above snippet. There is no difference between the two snippet button1 font family. Both the places it applied `courier` font only. Only the background is getting different because it is applying the default styles for the button.

Now let us know, Still any specific issue you have???

Comment: I thought I had edited my original post to fix that mistake (`42px` instead of `42`).  Anyway, it's fixed now.
Still the same result -- the font-size does NOT take effect in Chrome for the button, nor does the font-family.  As soon as the `background:  pink;` declaration is inserted, the button shows the expected font-size and font-family.

Comment: And by the way, Chrome doesn't seem to care whether it's 42 or 42px (not that it isn't a mistake; just explaining why it's an easy one to make ;-))

Comment: Above snippets are working fine right. can you reproduce it anywhere??

Comment: Suresh, I cannot now.  I tried making a new page and using both the original snippet, and the one above (with "42" instead of "42px"), both now work.
I'm almost wondering if it was some caching issue.  I know for a fact it failed for me on a separate page.

Comment: If you can't able to reproduce your issue then you can close your question.